# Identify the test device for Admob

Tags: swift, admob

I use the code below:

`let request : GADRequest = GADRequest ()`

`request.testDevices = ["xxxxxxx",kGADSimulatorID]`

But I am getting the below warning:

> 'testDevices' is deprecated: Use GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers.

Do I use a syntax to remove the warning?

Comment: Without `request`, I've used it this way and no more warnings:   `GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = ["xxxxxx", kGADSimulatorID] as? [String]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use this:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = ["YOUR IDENTIFIER PRINTED ON DEBUGGER"]
```

Instead of:

```
request.testDevices = ["YOUR IDENTIFIER PRINTED ON DEBUGGER"]
```

Comment: Hello, sorry can you tell me in what place of my code I need to use: GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = ["YOUR IDENTIFIER PRINTED ON DEBUGGER"] ?

Comment: You can use it anywhere, also in the ViewDidload

Answer (score 3):

### Swift Solution

It turns out the `AdMob`/`GoogleAdManager` `deviceId` can be found by computing the [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) of the [advertisingIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager). This way you can retrieve and use the test `deviceId` in code without having to previously have got a device's identifier from the console log.

To avoid the faff of using an ObjC-Swift bridging header (getting MD5 via `<CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>`), I'd suggest using a Swift wrapper around the `CommonCrypto` framework, e.g this one:

- [SwiftCrypto](https://github.com/jernejstrasner/SwiftCrypto)

Using the above framework (which adds an extension property to `String` for computing the MD5 hash), it is a simple matter of querying against:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers ?? []).contains(ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString.md5)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a modification to [10623169](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10623169/10623169)'s answer.

To get a valid ID, for the current device, that can be set in "testDevices", get the **MD5** of this: `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString`

The `asIdentifier` value can be completely invalid if the user hasn't given permission for tracking. But the `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor` is a valid UUID for the app, that will persist across launches (but perhaps not if you delete the app and reinstall).

Answer (score 1):

Use the syntax to remove the warning:

```
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers
```

Comment: where should i use it in flutter ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to set this at all. As the AdMob Developer Doc says:

> iOS simulators are automatically configured as test devices.

Source: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads#enable_test_devices

Comment: Need for real devices.

Comment: if you don't need that, why they log "<Google> To get test ads on this device, set: GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];" ?

Comment: Yeah, I understand that I can look at the log... But what I'd like to do is build a version of the app that will be used internally, and connect to our "QA" systems. So, I'd like _anyone_ that tests our app internally to see test-ads, on their device.  What I *don't* want to do is ask each of our internal users for their device-ID in this log, and hardcode that into the app somewhere. I just want any person running the "QA" version of the app to be treated as a "test device"

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Solution**

Works with disabled app tracking. Without any external dependencies.

```
import CryptoKit


var deviceId = ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString
if deviceId == UUID(0).uuidString {
  deviceId = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString ?? ""
}

let md5 = Insecure.MD5.hash(data: Data(deviceId.utf8))
    .map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [ md5 ]
```